# How to exit wmii interface?

Tags: login

I installed wmii on my Ubuntu14.04, so I can select which interface to use at the log-in interface.

But now I need to install a new language, which requires me to go back to Ubuntu original desktop. I want to quit wmii interface instead of restart the machine.

Can I do that， how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enter the wmii menu, use combination key:

```
modkey-a
```

(the default modifier key `modkey` is the <kbd>Windows</kbd>, on mac is <kbd>cmd</kbd>, but it may be also <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

then type:

```
exec
```

or

```
quit
```

and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

This will shutdown wmii and return to login screen.